# Как создать словарь из 2 списков?

Tags: python, list, словари

Цель: Объединить два списка в словарь. Списки одинаковой длины.
Почему из двух списков одинаковой длины, получается короткий словарь?

Такой код наполняет список:

```
diapazoni1 = []
diapazoni2 = []

for s in ss:
    r_d = n_f_d * s
    if r_d != 0:
        opisanie_diapazona = f'Это д{s}, н д, {r_d}'
        print(opisanie_diapazona)
        diapazoni1.append(s)
        diapazoni2.append(r_d)
    if r_d == 0:
        r_d = r_d + s
        opisanie_diapazona = f'Это д{s}, н д, {r_d},'
        print(opisanie_diapazona)
        diapazoni1.append(s)
        diapazoni2.append(r_d)

diapazon1 = [260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 64, 7, 72]
```

Длина списка = 234

```
diiapazon2 = [210, 10, 2, 2, 6, 230, 5, 2, 10, 14, 62, 1, 14, 211, 11, 3, 3, 3, 51, 6, 3, 1, 15, 27, 7, 51, 165, 5, 9, 1, 5, 245, 2, 5, 5, 29, 29, 1, 29, 145, 5, 2, 1, 5, 245, 2, 5, 5, 29, 29, 5, 29, 38, 18, 12, 2, 6, 38, 2, 2, 8, 2, 54, 4, 38, 149, 9, 6, 1, 5, 29, 2, 5, 9, 29, 13, 4, 29, 230, 10, 9, 2, 6, 110, 2, 2, 10, 2, 38, 5, 38, 88, 8, 10, 4, 8, 48, 3, 12, 8, 12, 56, 2, 48, 27, 7, 1, 3, 7, 167, 5, 11, 7, 23, 23, 2, 23, 118, 18, 1, 2, 2, 98, 8, 2, 8, 26, 42, 7, 26, 90, 10, 12, 2, 6, 150, 6, 6, 10, 6, 54, 3, 6, 32, 12, 6, 4, 4, 172, 1, 4, 2, 28, 28, 7, 28, 59, 19, 7, 3, 3, 259, 7, 7, 9, 7, 3, 2, 43, 12, 12, 12, 4, 4, 292, 4, 4, 2, 4, 52, 3, 4, 183, 3, 1, 3, 3, 323, 8, 11, 3, 35, 51, 4, 35, 198, 18, 3, 2, 6, 38, 2, 2, 8, 2, 14, 1, 38, 260, 20, 13, 4, 8, 360, 9, 12, 10, 36, 16, 1, 72, 187, 7, 5, 3, 3, 187, 7, 7, 7, 7, 11, 6, 43]
```

длина списка = 234

```
two_list_in_dict_d1_d2 = dict(zip(diapazoni1, diapazoni2))
{260: 187, 20: 7, 13: 5, 4: 3, 8: 3, 360: 187, 9: 7, 12: 7, 10: 7, 36: 7, 64: 11, 7: 6, 72: 43}

Как сделать так {260:210, 20:10,......}
```

Списки на выходе имеют одинаковый размер, но после упаковки, получается короткий словарь, и ключ значение не соответствует последовательности {1:1, 2:2}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(diapazon1))
```

Вывод:

```
Counter({260: 18, 20: 18, 13: 18, 4: 18, 8: 18, 360: 18, 9: 18, 12: 18, 10: 18, 36: 18, 64: 18, 7: 18, 72: 18})
```

Ключи вашего словаря повторяются по 18 раз каждый. Словарь не может содержать одинаковые ключи несколько раз. В словаре сохраняется только самая последняя пара ключ-значение в этом случае, что мы и наблюдаем.

Если вы всё же хотите хранить пары с одинаковым значением ключа, то вам подойдёт либо:

- список кортежей `[(k1, v1), (k2, v2), ...]`
- либо словарь, значения которого не числа, а списки `{k1: [v11, v12, v13, ...], k2: [...], ...}`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Получается  объединить списки таким способом `dict(zip(diapazoni1, diapazoni2))` , не удастся?

Comment: @dog3000 Я немного дополнил ответ какие есть варианты. В виде словаря с парой ключ:значение вида число:число - не удастся.